# cannot display images uploaded into a folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

this is AdminUsersController method!!!!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UsersRequest;
use App\Photo;
use App\Role;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

  class AdminUsersController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    //
   $users = User::all();



    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
}


public function create()
{
    //

    $roles = Role::lists('name','id')->all();

    return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles'));

}


public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    //

    $input = $request->all();


    if($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {

        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move('images', $name);

        $photo = Photo::create(['file'=> $name]);

        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;

    }

    $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
    User::create($input);

   return redirect('/admin/users');




}


public function show($id)
{
    //

    return view('admin.users.show');
}


public function edit($id)
{
    //

    return view('admin.users.edit');
}


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}


public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

By this images are uploaded to /public/images

This is code im using to display in index.blade.php

```
 <img src="/images/{{$user->photo ? $user->photo->file : 'no user photo'}}" alt="">
```

but images are not displayed in webpage i don't know why!!! please help me with this

my routes code:

```
<?php



Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::get('/admin', function(){

return view('admin.index');

 });


 Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
```

this is my code in index.blade.php

```
 <h1>users</h1>



 <table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Photo</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Updated</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

 @if($users)
     @foreach($users as $user)

<tr>
    <td>{{$user->id}}</td>

    <td><img scr="/images/{{$user->photo ? $user->photo->file : 'no user photo'}}"></td>
    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->is_active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Not Active' }}"</td>
    <td>{{$user->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
</tr>

      @endforeach
 @endif

</tbody>
```

[this is my output in which i cannot display photos but photo is uploaded into /public/images folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPl2C.png)

Comment: Can you please add a bit of information about your routes set up? also, can you include what output you get from the form if your blade code just before the img is `<div>{!! dd($user->photo) !!}`

Comment: if i use your code its just saying null

Comment: dd = dump and die, so your code is not providing a value

Comment: Suggest you show how you are injecting the $user value in your controller. If you change to just $user you will probably find you are not setting that either

Comment: check once again my post plzz i hav added routes and output image please help me

Comment: so when you do a dd($user) what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey first of all to show an image with laravel you need to use `{{asset(..)}}` in your `<img/>` ... example :

```
<img src="{{asset('...')}}" alt="">
```

then you will need to store your photos in public folder by using `public_path()` function for exemple

```
$imageName = $user->id.'.'.'jpg';
        $request->file('img')->move(
            public_path() . '/img/', $imageName
        );
```

now to show the photo of your user in the public path or storage path you need to do this for exemple :

```
<img src="{{asset('/img/user->photo')}}" alt="">
```

I hope that will help you

Comment: Hi, can you describe your problem ?

Comment: Assets, in my opinion, should only be used for the applications on use. Not user uploads. It's messy and a bad practice - not to mention, not very secure.

Comment: I appreciate  your opinion , i can explain showing Image by sending variables to a route,  and storing Images in a Filesystem Disks like S3...  this will be more secure but very long to explain here.